# Android: Display images in full screen mode using Picasso

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

Hi i have some images displayed in gridView using Picasso, when i try to open each image (after onItemClickListener) in full screen mode (inside new acivity) it display only the first image in my gridView whatever the image i click, this is my problem.
This is my code where i display the images from the url inside gridView and OnItemClickListener.

```
Picasso.with(ToolDescription.this)
       .load(SaveSettings.ServerURL +"Images/"+ imagepath)
       .into(imageView);

       ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ToolDescription.this, ImageFull.class);
                intent.putExtra("imagepath", SaveSettings.ServerURL +"Images/"+ imagepath);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

            return myView;
```

This is my second activity (named ImageFull) where i want to display the clicked image:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
String imagepath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagepath");

    Picasso.with(ImageFull.this)
                .load(imagepath)
                .noFade()
                .resize(800, 800)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set an individual click listener to each imageview or use the int position to pull the correct imagepath from your gridview item array.

[Grid View Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

This link has a easy to follow code for exactly what you're trying to do..  Use the position to find which element you are clicking on an get the respective image url

Comment: Thanks @AcidBurn314

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what's happening is that you're calling `ls.setOnItemClickListener()` every time `getView()` returns.

`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` is a single listener for the entire `AdapterView`, and you're intended to differentiate *which* item was clicked on by using its `position` argument.

I'm not sure where `imagepath` is coming from inside `getView()`, but I assume it's something like `String imagepath = getItem(position).getImagePath()`. If that is the case, you can fix your problem by:

1) Move `ls.setOnItemClickListener()` out of `getView()`... probably to your `onCreate()` or whever you set up your `GridView`.

2) Change

```
intent.putExtra("imagepath", SaveSettings.ServerURL +"Images/"+ imagepath);
```

to

```
String currentImagePath = getItem(position).getImagePath();
intent.putExtra("imagepath", SaveSettings.ServerURL +"Images/"+ currentImagePath);
```

Probably there will be syntax errors because I can't see the rest of your code, but hopefully this is enough for you to be able to work through them.

Comment: Thanks So much @Ben P great answer